# what is the data storage type for .net Stack data type?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, linked-list, stack

As we can create our own stack data types or use the .Net platforms built in stack I want to know what underlying data type does the stack use?

is it the Single linked Linked, double linked list or an array?

what are the performance impacts of using whichever data type is used for the stacks?

Comment: Are you talking about `Stack<T>` ? or the "stack is an implementation detail for local variables"?

Comment: why don't you use something like ILSpy and see it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about stack<T>. I found out that this uses Array.

Comment: @ravikumar Why would you do that and not looking at the publicly published original source? Or, for that matter, looking at the official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the [official documentation on stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx), and you can see that it uses an internal array increasing strategy similar to List.